# Is here any trick for multiplication Sn permutations in this example

Tags: permutations

I've got problem with permutation group multiplication.

Here is an example:

Determine the permutation $\alpha = S_9 $ is that $ \alpha*\omega * \alpha^{-1} = \gamma$ . How much of those permutations we have?

$ \omega= (13624)(587)(9) $ and $\gamma = (15862)(394)(7)$

$ \alpha*\omega * \alpha^{-1} = \gamma$

Is here any trick to do this? I will be very thankful for every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a trick, or more specifically a theorem. It says that for $(i_1,...,i_k) \in S_n$, $$\alpha\cdot (i_1,...,i_k) \cdot \alpha^{-1}=(\alpha(i_1),...,\alpha(i_k)).$$ In particular, $$\alpha \omega \alpha^{-1}=\alpha (13624)\alpha^{-1}\alpha (587)\alpha^{-1}\alpha (9)\alpha^{-1}=(15862)(394)(7).$$ So you're looking for $\alpha \in S_n$ such that $\alpha(1)=1,\alpha(3)=5,\alpha(6)=8$, etc...